# Ask password after suspend

Tags: suspend

I have disabled authorization after start PC. But after suspend it ask me password. How i can disable this dialogue? 
It must be in Settings\Power - there is enough place for it. But there only 3 options.

Answer (score 1):

Just go System Settings \ Security & Privacy

[image]

PS: if developers read this! Please copy this settings to "Power" menu! Its like Keyboards and Shortcuts for switching layouts must be in one place for quick access!

Comment: I totally agree with the PS, but the best way to give feedback to the dev team is by posting an issue on https://github.com/elementary